# How do I set up in-app purchasing in iOS?

Tags: c#, unity, ios, monetization

I am using Unity and I developing an app for iOS. How do I implement in-app purchases that work world-wide?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple provides a framework for in-app purchasing in StoreKit.  You can read the docs on it [here](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/).  From their documentation:

> Store Kit communicates with the App Store on behalf of your
>   application. Your application uses Store Kit to receive localized
>   information from the App Store about products you want to offer in
>   your application. Your application displays this information to users
>   and allows them to purchase items. When a user wants to purchase an
>   item, your app calls Store Kit to collect payment from the user.
>   Figure 1-1 shows the basic store model.

[image]

How to implement in-app purchasing is more involved than the format here permits, but the general areas that you're going to need to learn about are:

- Retrieving Product Information from the App Store
- Making a Purchase from the App Store
- Adding a Store to Your Application
- Verifying Store Receipts
- Testing your store
- Auto-renewable subscriptions (possibly).

Here are some additional resources you may want to look at:

- [Unity3D's docs on in-app purchasing](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/iphone-Downloadable-Content.html).
- [StoreKit Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/StoreKit_Collection/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008300)
- [App Store Resource Center](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/index.html) - addresses the business side of in-app purchasing.
- [Prime31's unity plugin](http://prime31.com/plugins) for storekit.

Comment: probably he need to emebed the framework inside a Unity3D plugin, is that right?

Comment: First I would like to thank Cameron. Thank you. Second, yes I need a Unity3D plugin or a framework to work within Unity like Heisenbug is stating.

Comment: @karsnen I added a few additional links, including Prime31's plugin, which is pretty popular.

Comment: @karsnen sure thing.  Glad you found it useful. :)